# Removing old rvm ruby-version files

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

When I change ruby-version files e.g. `rvm --ruby-version use a.b.c@rails_4`
I get a message along the lines

```
.ruby-version is not empty, moving aside to preserve.
.ruby-gemset is not empty, moving aside to preserve.
```

and two new files are created that store the old version of the ruby version and gems name.  This clutters up my root directory, is there an flag to stop this happening? If not, any reasons why I should not just delete the old version files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rvm --ruby-version use a.b.c@rails_4` command is used to **create** `.ruby-version` file that represents your project's Ruby version. This file is intended to be stored in your repository, but I guess you already know that.

Anyways, as the [docs say](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects), it is used for *creating* and *not updating* or anything. So, it is logical that RVM first backs up existing `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files before generating the new ones.

You can delete those backed up files. If you want to update the ruby version of your project just edit existing `.ruby-*` files. It is much easier IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, in future I will just edit the .ruby-* files.